# Does VSCode can escape text when pasting into a string literal?

Tags: string, visual-studio-code

Eclipse has an option that copy-paste of multi-line text into String literals will result in quoted newlines.

Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing > Escape text when pasting into a string literal

Does vscode can do it?

for example

**copy bellow and paste:**

some text    with tabs
and new 
lines

**Then eclipse change like this:**

"some text\twith tabs\r\n" +
"and new \r\n" +
"lines"

How can I do it in vscode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't at this moment. There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20771) for this at [backlog](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/8) without an estimation.

There is a [plugin at marketplace](https://github.com/gwicksted/paste-escaped) that does the job, but for TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug that works for JavaScript and others now: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cvbge.escape-string

- C
- C++
- C#
- JavaScript
- Python
- TypeScript